# GraphQL Subscriptions do not execute nested Resolvers

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, graphql-subscriptions

There is a

- query **player** and
- subscription **playerJoinedTable**.

Both should return **PlayerType** and both receive object with property **profileId**.

PlayerType has property **profile** with resolver:

```
profile: {
  type: ProfileType,
  resolve: (obj, args, {db}) => {
    return db.collection('profiles').findOne({_id: ObjectID(obj.profileId)})
  }
}
```

When server is asked for query **player** it returns both fields from players table and **profile** object with profile fields.

But when subscription below:

```
playerJoinedTable: {
  type: PlayerType,
  resolve: payload => payload,
  subscribe: () => pubsub.asyncIterator('playerJoinedTable')
```

is executed, the server returns only **player's** own fields without executing **profile's** resolver.

Output:
[image]

Any idea why the subscription doesn't execute nested resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oskar!

Looks like you have an error in the `playerJoinedTable > profile` resolver.
Seems that you're trying to access the `collection` on `db` (i think), but `db` is undefined.

Make sure the server doesn't start listening before you pass `db` to the context

Comment: Yeah, I missed `db` in the context for SubscriptionServer. Thanks!